# render nunjucks template in the browser

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

Part of the nunjucks template consists of variables which I would like to set after the page was sent to the browser. Currently it would also needs to [import](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#import) other templates.

Do I need to preinclude the other [imported](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#import) templates?

Comment: Maybe [custom syntax](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#customizing-syntax) for each step?

Comment: @AikonMogwai would work but I would prefere to do just exclude certain functions

Comment: Another way is to use [custom tags](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#custom-tags) (separating for each step). But the custom syntax is more transparency.

Comment: @AikonMogwai that's exactly what i was looking for ... thank you!

Comment: @AikonMogwai Answer is correct and based on the question "only render part of the template in nunjucks" which didn't capture the whole aspect of my question. Check the editing history,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to to this is by using a [custom loader](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#asynchronous).

First you send the unrendered template to the client. (You don't need to prerender the imports) Then you write a custom loader where you can define how the imports should be loaded.

Example (I used type as an extra GET parameter to define that the template should not be rendered):

```
var customLoader = {getSource:"",async:true};
customLoader.getSource = function(name, cb) {
    var reqPath = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + name + "?type=view";
    $.get(reqPath, (data) => {
        cb(null, {src:data, path:reqPath});
    }); 
}

var env = new nunjucks.Environment(customLoader);
```

Then you can use the env callback to render the template:

```
env.renderString(theInitialTemplate, yourJSONData, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res); //do something with the res variable
});
```

In this example I used an async loader. You can use new Promise to load both the model and the view and afterwards check with Promise.all to put both together and render the template.